# When i run react native on android im getting this error : ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

it is working in ios but come to run in android show this error.

> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android
>   development environment set up:
>   https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment.
>   Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. Error: Command failed:
>   ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
> - Try: Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 4s
>
> ```
> at makeError (/Users/sherin/CourierApp/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
> at /Users/sherin/CourierApp/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/sherin/CourierApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
> at async Command.handleAction (/Users/sherin/CourierApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
> ```

Comment: As error suggests, Kindly make sure you have running android development environment to start react-native application

Comment: those alla are perfect its working before 2 days.now its seems like this